# Issue with sb.lmplot()

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, seaborn, data-science

I want exploring linear relationships among my dataa with lmplot, but it returns an error.
Can someone help me to understand what is wrong in my code ?
I have cleaned my data eliminating null data and converting in float format the values that were in str format. After that I try to do the lmplot(). 
This is the link  where I found the csv file; [link](https://www.kaggle.com/amanarora/obesity-among-adults-by-country-19752016/data#obesity-cleaned.csv)

CODE

```py
#Analysis of obesity by country

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

address = 'C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/Python/firstMN/obesity-cleaned.csv'
dt = pd.read_csv(address)

#eliminate superfluos data
dt.drop(dt['Obesity (%)'][dt['Obesity (%)'].values == 'No data'].index, inplace=True)  

for i in range(len(dt)):
   dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i] = float(dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i].split()[0]) 

#print(dt['Country'], '\n') 
#print(dt['Obesity (%)'])

sb.lmplot('Country', 'Obesity (%)', dt) 
plt.show(
```

HEAD DATASET

```
   Unnamed: 0      Country  Year Obesity (%)         Sex
0           0  Afghanistan  1975         0.5  Both sexes
1           1  Afghanistan  1975         0.2        Male
2           2  Afghanistan  1975         0.8      Female
3           3  Afghanistan  1976         0.5  Both sexes
4           4  Afghanistan  1976         0.2        Male
5           5  Afghanistan  1976         0.8      Female
6           6  Afghanistan  1977         0.6  Both sexes
7           7  Afghanistan  1977         0.2        Male
8           8  Afghanistan  1977         0.9      Female
9           9  Afghanistan  1978         0.6  Both sexes
```

OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Python\firstMN\obesity.py", line 23, in <module>
    sb.lmplot('Country', 'Obesity (%)', dt)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 616, in lmplot
    facets.map_dataframe(regplot, x, y, **regplot_kws)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 828, in map_dataframe
    self._facet_plot(func, ax, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 846, in _facet_plot
    func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 817, in regplot
    plotter.plot(ax, scatter_kws, line_kws)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 369, in plot
    self.lineplot(ax, line_kws)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 412, in lineplot
    grid, yhat, err_bands = self.fit_regression(ax)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 200, in fit_regression
    grid = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in linspace
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 129, in linspace
    start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your csv?

Comment: Hi, NYC Coder. Yes, done

Comment: CSV is better. This is hard to copy.

Comment: I added the link where I found the file csv ; Obesity-cleaned.csv. I don't know how to share the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is for `lmplot` you need both numbers, you cant give 'Country' as x value. You need to use another plot here.

If you do this (although it makes no sense), it works

```
sb.lmplot(x='Year', y='Obesity (%)', data=dt) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much